# Quelle serait une formule plus nette de "J'y ai vu du jugement dans son attitude"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

Je cherche une formulation plus nette et élégante rendant compte de cette idée.

Comment: Un peu de contexte pour expliquer le sens de la phrase ne serait pas malvenu.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne comprends aussi pourquoi 'y' et 'dans' dans la même phrase. Est-il idiomatique ?

Comment: @Dimitris : non ce n'est pas une tournure standard. Leur présence rend la phrase maladroite et difficile à interpréter.

Comment: Contexte: Au cours d'une discussion, une femme a roulé les yeux, cela m'a donné l'impression qu'elle montrait du jugement.

Comment: Au cours d'une discussion, une femme a vu/perçu [du | une forme de] jugement dans [son attitude | l'attitude de …]

Comment: @Dimitris ça me semble être une tournure régionale, dans l'est (Lyon, Besançon) on rajoute beaucoup de "y" dans ce style

Comment: Cette utilisation de "jugement" semble calqué sur l'anglais "judgmental" pour décrire l'attitude ou les propos de quelqu'un.

Comment: @XouDo J’ai quelques questions qui, à ce jour, demeurent en suspens. Si vous aviez l’amabilité d’y jeter un coup d’oeil et dans le meilleur des cas d’y répondre, je vous en serais fortement reconnaissante!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a deux problèmes dans la formulation originale:

1. L'expression ***voir du jugement*** n'est pas idiomatique. On fait preuve de jugement, mais on aura du mal à "voir" un jugement, sauf dans un tribunal...
2. *J'**y** ai vu du xxx **dans** xxx* contient une redondance maladroite du pronom et de son référent.

On pourra écrire, en choisissant les variantes suivant le sens précis attendu :

> J'ai **remarqué**/**senti**/**saisi** dans son **attitude**/**geste** une **marque**/un **signe** de **discernement**/**lucidité**/**clairvoyance**/**bon sens**.

Edit: Après clarification, le jugement est négatif:

> J'ai **remarqué**/**senti**/**saisi** dans son **attitude**/**geste** une **marque**/un **signe** de **désapprobation**/**réprobation**.

Comment: Salut jiliagre, d'abord merci pour ta réponse. Ce que je cherchais à exprimer, c'est que j'avais l'impression d'être jugé défavorablement et que mon interlocuteur donnait l'impression de ne pas adhérer à mon point de vue. Le roulement des yeux de la personne à qui je m'adressais semblait marquer son désaccord.

Comment: @Pas un clue. ??

Comment: Devrais-je me garder d'employer le terme "jugement" et  préférer le nom "critique"?

Comment: Ah, donc il ne s'agit pas de jugement dans un sens positif mais jugement dans le sens du juge. Je modifie ma réponse dans ce sens.

Answer (score 2):

Quelques façons de formuler cette idée :

- J'ai perçu dans son attitude qu'il faisait preuve de jugement.
- De par son attitude, je peux dire qu'il montre du jugement.
- J'ai vu que son attitude montrait du jugement.
- J'ai vu par son attitude que c'était un homme/une femme de jugement.

Faire attention à ne pas considérer cette phrase comme lourde dans tous les contextes ; elle peut être trouvée préférable dans un contexte comme celui du dialogue suivant.

— Je n'ai pas trouvé qu'il soit particulièrement intéressant, ni même très logique ; son attitude ne m'inspire pas confiance.
— J'y ai vu du jugement dans son attitude…

Bien que l'on puisse aussi dire « J'ai vu du jugement… », la redondance (y, attitude) est souvent considérée comme plus expressive.